# T-SQL: Efficient way of creating an aggregate view of four joined tables (max audit-entry per audit type for each item)

Tags: sql, performance, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-ce

Some help with some T-SQL would be most appreciated.

I have the following four tables:

- Item (Id)
- ItemVersion (Id, FK many-to-one Item.Id)
- ItemVersionStatusLog (LogDate, FK many-to-one ItemVersion.Id, FK many-to-one StatusType.Id)
- StatusType (Id, Alias)

I've only listed the columns appropriate to this question.

The root entity is an `Item`. For each `Item`, there is one or more `ItemVersion` entries. For each `ItemVersion` entry, there is one or more `ItemVersionStatusLog` entries with a date and a reference to a `StatusType` (e.g. created, updated, disabled).

I'd like to summarise the "most recent status" of each `Item` by creating an aggregate view in a new table (`ItemStatus`) that I'll backfill and then keep updated when data changes. The aggregation should give me the maximum-dated entry in the log table, for each Item and  `StatusType` pair. So that I have a snapshot of, for each `StatusType`, I can get the most recent `ItemVersion` for an Item.

Another way of putting it is procedurally:

```
For each Item
- For each StatusType
- - List the ItemVersion Id with the maximum date from ItemVersionStatusLog given the correct StatusType
```

My target columns for the aggregate view or table are:

```
Item Id, ItemVersion Id, Date (from ItemVersionStatus), StatusType Id
```

While I could do this reasonably well with the use of UDF's, if possible I'd love to do this in a single SQL statement. My primary target is SQL Server 2008, but also SQL Server Compact 4 without much modification, so relying on UDF's isn't a great option but any help is appreciated :)

*Update - some example data*

```
Item:
Id
--
1
2
```

**ItemVersion:**

```
Id  | ItemId | Name
----------
1   | 1      | Apple
2   | 1      | Orange
3   | 1      | Plum
4   | 2      | Petrol
5   | 2      | Diesel
6   | 2      | LPG
```

**StatusType:**

```
Id  | Alias
-----------
1   | Created
2   | Approved
3   | Published
4   | Deleted
```

**ItemVersionStatusLog:**

```
Id  | ItemVersionId | StatusTypeId | Date
------------------------------------------
1   | 1             | 1            | 2012-01-01 00:00
2   | 1             | 4            | 2012-01-01 00:05
3   | 2             | 1            | 2012-01-01 00:10
4   | 2             | 3            | 2012-01-01 00:15
5   | 3             | 1            | 2012-01-01 00:20
6   | 3             | 3            | 2012-01-01 00:25
```

In this case the expected result for Item 1 would be:

**ItemStatus**

```
ItemId | ItemVersionId | Date             | StatusTypeId
--------------------------------------------------------
1      | 3             | 2012-01-01 00:20 | 1
1      | 3             | 2012-01-01 00:25 | 3
1      | 1             | 2012-01-01 00:05 | 4
```

Comment: What have you tried? And a sample of what data you have and what data you expect would be great.

Comment: Post some sample data set here, it doesn't needed be many rows, just a representative enough to give us a clearer picture of the problem, and  post its intended output. With sample data on question and its intended output, it can aid answerers more with their [rubberducking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: Done - hope that makes it clearer! Cheers

Comment: To the answerers, one tip, use http://sqlfiddle.com Text to DDL. Copy the OP's data, then paste it in Text to DDL, it will automatically create DDL and data sample `INSERT` statements. Thanks ツ

Comment: What if two dates are equal (and max).  And I think you mean VersionID 2 in the first row of the result.

Comment: If the two dates are equal and max, I'm happy to throw one away as I'm using a server-generated datetimeoffset(7) so it's accurate enough to disregard conflicts without too much of a worry (this isn't a finance system or anything). The example is correct - version 3 points to item 1, and version 3 also has the most recent instance of status 1. there are two earlier instances of status 1, but as per the question, version 3 wins - cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
With MostRecentStatus As
    (
    Select ItemVersionId, StatusTypeId, [Date]
        , Row_Number() Over ( Partition By StatusTypeId Order By [Date] Desc ) As Rnk
    From ItemVersionStatusLog As IVSL
    )
Select IV.ItemId, M.ItemVersionId, M.[Date], M.StatusTypeId
From MostRecentStatus As M
  Join ItemVersion As IV
    On IV.Id = M.ItemVersionId
Where Rnk = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2cdb8/12)

A version that does not use a CTE:

```
Select IV.ItemId, IVSL.ItemVersionId, IVSL.[Date], IVSL.StatusTypeId
From ItemVersionStatusLog As IVSL
  Join (
      Select  IVSL2.StatusTypeId, Max([Date]) As [Date]
      From ItemVersionStatusLog As IVSL2
      Group By IVSL2.StatusTypeId
      ) As Z
    On Z.StatusTypeId = IVSL.StatusTypeId
      And Z.[Date] = IVSL.[Date]
  Join ItemVersion As IV
    On IV.Id = IVSL.ItemVersionId
```

[SQL Fiddle Version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2cdb8/35)

One catch with the above solution is that it does not allow for multiple entries for the same status on the same date and time. If we can assume that in the case of such a tie, that the last `ItemVersionStatusLog.Id` value is to be used, then we would adjust like so:

```
Select IV.ItemId, IVSL.ItemVersionId, IVSL.[Date], IVSL.StatusTypeId
From ItemVersionStatusLog As IVSL
  Join (
      Select IVSL1.StatusTypeId, IVSL1.[Date], Max(IVSL1.Id) As Id
      From ItemVersionStatusLog As IVSL1
        Join (
            Select  IVSL2.StatusTypeId, Max([Date]) As [Date]
            From ItemVersionStatusLog As IVSL2
            Group By IVSL2.StatusTypeId
            ) As Z
          On Z.StatusTypeId = IVSL1.StatusTypeId
            And Z.[Date] = IVSL1.[Date]
      Group By IVSL1.StatusTypeId, IVSL1.[Date]
      ) As MostRecentStatus
    On MostRecentStatus.Id = IVSL.Id
  Join ItemVersion As IV
    On IV.Id = IVSL.ItemVersionId
```

[SQL Fiddle Version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2cdb8/39)

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting somewhere with this one after a few mods (partitioning on both the ItemId and the StatusTypeId because I need the maximum-dated result for each status type) - can you think of a way of doing this without a CTE though, so that I could run the same T-SQL in Sql Compact?

Comment: @AlexNorcliffe - I posted another version that does not use a CTE. Obviously, a CTE will be faster and more efficient but if CE doesn't then you have to go the more complicated route.

Comment: Your 2nd & 3rd solutions look great, however my decision to simplify the question by using integer IDs has bitten me :) I'm using GUID ids in each table, so can't do a Max on the ID. I do appreciate your time though and if you've no time to look into it further I'm happy to mark your question as an answer given the drawbacks in my question detail

Comment: @AlexNorcliffe - With respect to the integer Id's that's fine, it just means there is no simple tie-breaker in the case of two entries for the same status and date.

Comment: hmm that's odd I'm sure the 2nd example (without the CTE) had Max(id) in there - did you edit it? I'll try it again. Thanks!

Comment: @AlexNorcliffe - Btw, in theory you could still use the Id even if it was a guid. It would just mean that the system would in effect randomly choose one of the rows. You would simply need to change `Max(IVSL1.Id)` to `Max(Cast(IVSL1.Id As varchar(40)))`

Comment: @AlexNorcliffe - I did simplify the second solution and then expanded on it in the third solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live without ItemVersion.Id you could use a GROUP BY:

```
SELECT
  item.Id,
  MAX(log.LogDate) as LogDate,
  status.Id
FROM Item item
JOIN ItemVersion version ON item.Id = version.ItemId
JOIN ItemVersionStatusLog log ON version.Id = log.ItemVersionId
JOIN StatusType status ON log.StatusTypeId = status.Id
GROUP BY
  item.Id,
  status.Id
```

Comment: Thanks, although I do need the ItemVersion.Id, because the purpose of the aggregation is to know which version has the most recent status type (for each item). So let's say I need to know which is the most recently approved version for each item, but by querying a pre-calculated aggregate table rather than doing lots of subqueries each time